# Maximum Likelihood Estimation for a Unique Probability Density Function

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, estimators

In the context of estimating parameters for a uniquely distributed set of independent and identically distributed random variables, I am examining the following probability density function $ f(x|\theta) = \frac{3\theta^3}{x^4} \mathbf{1}_{[\theta,\infty)}(x) $ with $ \theta > 0 $.

(a) For the estimation, I am tasked to derive the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for $ \theta $ based on a sample $ X_1, \ldots, X_n $. I have started by setting up the likelihood function and taking the derivative with respect to $ \theta $, but I always get  that $\hat{\theta} = 0$ because:

$$\frac{\partial l(\theta \mid X)}{\partial \theta} = \frac{3n}{\theta}$$

Is this correct?

(b) After deriving the MLE, I need to determine its distribution and whether the estimator is unbiased for $ \theta $. I am aware that the unbiasedness of an estimator is linked to its expected value equalling the parameter. However, I am struggling to find the distribution of the MLE, how do I do this? Is there any theorem for the distribution of the MLE or there is a hidden "hint" in the question?

Comment: You probably meant the log-likelihood

Comment: Please provide the expression you derived for the (log-)likelihood

Comment: of course! The log-likelihood  that i've found is:

$$l (\theta \mid X) = n \log{3}  + 3n \log{\theta} - 4\log {\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i}$$

But i fell like im missing something, in this approach i completely ignored $\mathbf{1}_{[\theta,\infty)}(x)$ that is just a long way to say that the density is defined at the points where $x \ge \theta$

Comment: You shouldn't ignore that term

Comment: Best to edit the new information into the question as comments are not permanent.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you cannot ignore the indicator functions.

Note that, for $\theta \in \mathbb R_{> 0}, n \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^n \left[\frac{3\theta^3}{x_i^4} \mathbf 1_{\left[\theta, \infty\right)}\left(x_i\right)\right] 
&\overset{\theta}{\propto} \theta^{3n} \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1_{\left[\theta, \infty\right)}\left(x_i\right) \\ 
&= 
\begin{cases}
\theta^{3n}, &x_i\geq \theta  \;\forall i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}\\
0, &\text{otw.}
\end{cases} \\
&=
\begin{cases}
\theta^{3n}, &\theta \leq \min\left(\left\{x_i: i \in \left\{1, \ldots, n\right\}\right\}\right)\\
0, &\text{otw.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
for the likelihood function of $\theta$.

Also, $\theta \mapsto \theta^{3n}$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$ for $n \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}$.

Can you take it from here?